# Вывести посты внутри основного цикла Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Возможно ли в WP вывести посты определённой категории внутри поста?

Задача заключается в следующем, в теле поста нужно вывести несколько блоков (карточек/постов). Например, пост - это событие, а внутри этого поста выводится несколько участников события...

Обязательное условие выводить посты из другой категории внутри основного поста.

Реально это сделать на advanced custom fields? Получилось только вывести в нужном месте вывести id нужной категории и код, который выводит все посты внутри поста.
`

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'asc',
        'category' => $programId
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) { ?>

            <?php $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php }
    }
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
        $field = get_field("block_3", false, false);
        $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'category' => 11, 'include' => $field3, 'orderby' => 'name', 'order' => "ASC" );
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
            Мой цикл
        <?php endforeach;
        wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Реализовал так, изначально походу не правильно получал id.
Сейчас в посте через ACF выбираются нужные посты из указанной категории, которые выводятся в нужном месте цикла исходного поста.